# How can I send a NSDictionary/NSArray with the GameKit?

Tags: iphone, gamekit

I hear i should convert the dict to a propertylist and then send it and convert it back. Or is there a better way?

Anyway can someone show the code for the best solution?? Please don't post only the methods. I need a bit of code.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get `NSData` from a `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`. Use `NSKeyedArchiver` like this

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourDictionary];
```

Then back to `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver  unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

You might find useful to read [Apple's guide to archives and serialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i).